# Shouldn't free() accept a (void *const) as input arg

Tags: c, pointers, free

I was trying to understand the working of free. 
Is it defined in the standards that `free()` will not change the pointer which it was passed?

Comment: It is not defined.  Should `free()` change the pointer that is passed to it is irrelevant to the calling code.

Comment: Does that also mean I can't double free a NULL pointer? Is that defined?

Comment: You can call `free(NULL)` or `free(0)` - no bad effects.   it is defined  (Nothing happens)

Comment: You can do something like this: `char *a = NULL; free(a); free(a);` with no bad effects.

Comment: It's not clear whether you know that `void * const` is different than `const void *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In standard C argument passing is by value. So a function cannot change the value of its argument (and this is not specific to `free`). Every call is a [call by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). If inside a function you change some argument only a local copy (e.g. in some machine register) of that argument is changed and the caller does not see any change.

If you want to change something, you'll pass the address of that something as a value and you'll dereference that pointer.

Hence `free` won't change the pointer you pass to it, but you need to be sure to never use that pointer again. Otherwise, that is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A common style is to code `free(ptr), ptr=NULL;` (so that any further access thru `ptr` would crash with a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)).

In practice, most implementations of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) are marking a `free`-d zone to be reusable by future `malloc`. But sometimes (notably when freeing a large memory zone) the memory is released to the kernel (e.g. by [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) on Linux). What really happens to the memory zone is implementation specific.

Read wikipages of [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) & [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Look also inside the source code of some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C standard library implementation (e.g. most `libc` on Linux, such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)...). Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The const storage type tells the compiler that you do not intend to modify a block of memory once allocated (dynamically, or statically). Freeing memory is modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `free` changes the input argument or not relevant to the calling code. The calling code still has the pointer. It is similar to passing an `int` to a function. The called function may change the variable but it is change of the copy, not the original.

```
void foo(int i)
{
   i += 2;
}

void bar()
{
   int i = 10;
   foo(i);
}
```

Here, the change made to `i` in `foo` does not change the value of `i` in `bar.

Similarly,

```
void free(void* ptr)
{
   // Do the needful to deallocate
   ...
     ptr = NULL;
}

void test()
{
    char* p = malloc(10);
    ...
    free(p);
}
```

Here, the change made to `ptr` in `free` does not change the value of the pointer in `test`. Hence, it does not make much sense to make the argument of `free` to be of type `void* const`.